# addChild() - DisplayObject isn't visible immediately

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flex4

When I add a *DisplayObject* to a *DisplayObjectContainer* (e.g. a *Sprite* to a *Sprite*) in a function, it seems that the *DisplayObject* is actually added not immediately, but after finishing the function.

See this example:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class AddChildTest extends Sprite {

        private var _sprite:Sprite;

        public function AddChildTest():void{            
            var button:Sprite = new Sprite();
            button.graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00);
            button.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
            button.graphics.endFill();
            button.buttonMode = true;
            button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
            addChild(button);               
        }

        private function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
            _sprite = new Sprite();
            _sprite.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
            _sprite.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
            _sprite.graphics.endFill();
            _sprite.x = 50;
            _sprite.y = 50;                     

            //this red sprite is not visible immediateley!
            addChild(_sprite);      

            //put something time-consuming here
            for (var i:int = 0; i < 2000; i++){
                trace(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So we have a simple green button, and when it is clicked, there's a red *Sprite* constructed and added to the stage.
But actually the red *Sprite* isn't visible until the *onClick()* function has been fully executed.

Why is that and what can I do for the red *Sprite* to be visible immediately?

Is there some (for the developer invisible) global *paint()* or *update()* function, that is not executed until some stack is fully executed or something?

Comment: Try this.invalidateDisplayList()

Comment: A Sprite is not an mx.core.UIComponent, so this function doesn't exist there.

Comment: oops didn't notice it was a sprite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more related to the single threaded nature of Flash than anything else. The way it works is that it executes any code that is in response to an interaction event (your code). Then, any code that is in response to a prerender event (not used that much) and once all that is done, finally renders.

This flow of events [has been likened to an elastic racetrack](http://ted.onflash.org/2008/04/flash-player-mental-model-elastic.php).

Should your code take a very long time to run, this will delay the subsequent rendering.

So, if you want to display a progress indicator or similar you will at the very least need to wait with your processing to the next time around the "track", preferably split over multiple frames to keep your UI nice and responsive. The simplest version of this would be to use a timer to delay the calculations ever so slightly.

```
 private function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    // add sprite here

    var t:Timer = new Timer(50, 1);

    // i'm using an anonymous function here, however, a proper event handler 
    // function is probably cleaner

    t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.COMPLETE, function(e:Event):void {
        //put something time-consuming here
        for (var i:int = 0; i < 2000; i++){
            trace(i);
        }
    }
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: Chose this one as accepted answer as the posted link helped me a lot to better understand the topic.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some (for the developer invisible) global paint() or update()
>   function, that is not executed until some stack is fully executed or
>   something?

Yes there is something. Here a random link (via google): http://blog.johannest.com/2009/05/22/the-movieclip-life-cycle-event-frame_constructed-and-event-exit_frame/

Your screen is drawn or redrawn not until all frame code is executed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but... well, I'm from Java and don't know much about the frame-thing concept. :-) I'm developing a pure AS3 application. Seems like I need to get a little deeper into Flashs mechanics...

Comment: If you have blocking code, try to improve its performance. If not possible, try to use asynchronous processing using the Timer object.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is relevant regarding frame construction, be also advised that several useful events are available to help you deal with the display list slugginess on objects adding/removing:

```
  private function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
        _sprite = new Sprite();
        _sprite.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
        _sprite.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
        _sprite.graphics.endFill();
        _sprite.x = 50;
        _sprite.y = 50;                     

        //this red sprite is not visible immediateley!
        _sprite.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onReady);
        addChild(_sprite);      

    }

  private function onReady(e: Event): void {

        _sprite.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onReady);

        //put something time-consuming here
        for (var i:int = 0; i < 2000; i++){
            trace(i);
        }
    }
```

Here an Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE is listened, prior to launching the time-consuming routine, so the screen is not left empty.

Comment: I have tested your code because I was wondering if I did misunderstand something. The red box appears delayed in your example, too. When calling `addChild()` all event handlers for `ADDED_TO_STAGE` are executed right away. The rendering will be made after all listeners are triggered.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the following:

**The flash player renders the display list frame-wise**. It dispatches `Event.ENTER_FRAME`, to prepare for rendering (move around play heads in MovieClips etc.), then `Event.RENDER` (supposing you invalidated the stage), **then renders** and then dispatches `Event.EXIT_FRAME` after having left.

Therefore, any **subsequent changes** to the display list **will not be visible before the next frame is rendered - unless forced**.

However, between exit frame and the next enter frame, all events from I/O and timers are being dispatched. The mouse is also in input device, thus `MouseEvent`s are processed at this moment.

Some events - not all, but the most important ones including `MouseEvent`, `TimerEvent` and `KeyboardEvent` - have an `updateAfterEvent` method, that will **force the flash player to render** immediately after the event is processed.

Please note, that this option should be handled with care. If your framerate drops so far, that you see the delay between the mouse event being processed and the changes being rendered, forcing more rendering on the player might not be the best idea.